# Update all elements in array with same value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of users and want to set age = 0 if there´s no age present

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([{name: 'john', age: 40}, {name: 'mary'}, {name: 'mike'}])
```

how can I do this? (I don´t have access to the database to set all users age to 0 if there´s no age set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do:

```
setUsers(users.map(user => ({...user, age: user.age || 0})))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is will help.

```
const users = [{name: 'john', age: 40}, {name: 'mary'}, {name: 'mike'}]
users.map(user => {
  if (user.age === undefined) user.age = 0;
  return user;
});

setUsers(users);
```

Comment: If you're not using the new array returned by `map`, you might as well use `forEach`

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion! @Phil

Comment: I mean, there's nothing wrong with using `.map()` for this but it's not exactly fit-for-purpose

Comment: I´m now confused with the difference between both methods. forEach doesn´t modify the original array?

Comment: That's the point, forEach modifies the original array. Map ca do the same, as in the example, but the semantics is that it will return a new array. This means that people, looking at map, will expect the returned object to be used.